# matlab corrcoef two signals--what calculated?

Tags: matlab

How exactly does corrcoef calculate correlation between two signals X and Y?

What is the eqn? The help says it removes the mean from each column before calculation.

I have two 1D signals i'd like to compare with corrcoef.

Comment: You might want to take a look here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html . Also I did not find any mention to the mean removal.

Comment: Thanks. Ive read that. Here it says mean is removed from each column: http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/matlab/toolbox/signal/corrcoef.html

Comment: My bad! At least it has the equations used

Comment: @2one Did that answer your question or do you need further clarification?

Comment: no would still like a full explanation of the equation (calculation) and mean subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the documentation (from the octave function, which btw is deprecated):

> Function File:  corrcoef (X) Function File:  corrcoef (X, Y)  Compute
>   matrix of correlation coefficients.
>
> If each row of X and Y is an observation and each column is a 
>   variable, then the (I, J)-th entry of `corrcoef (X, Y)' is the 
>   correlation between the I-th variable in X and the J-th variable  in
>   Y.
>
> corrcoef(x,y) = cov(x,y)/(std(x)*std(y))
>
> If called with one argument, compute `corrcoef (X, X)', the 
>   correlation between the columns of X.
>
> See also: cov

So the function compares each column in input `X` to each column in input `Y`, one pair of columns at a time. For each pair of columns it computes the correlation coefficient:

```
 corrcoef(x,y) = cov(x,y)/(std(x)*std(y))
```

The covariance `cov` is computed as follows:

```
x = center (x, 1);
y = center (y, 1);
c = conj (x' * y / (n - 1));
```

where `n` is the number of points in x (and y) and `center` subtracts the mean from the data.